# Given a string input, how to check if a variable with the same name exists

Tags: python

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [5,6,7]
z = input("Enter which variable to use x or y: ")
```

now I want use the variable x or y depending on whether the input is "x" or "y"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 6):

Please, please, please, please, please don't use runtime variable reading. Instead, just use a dict:

```py
lists = {
    "x": [1, 2, 3],
    "y": [5, 6, 7]
}
z = input("Enter which variable to use x or y: ").strip()
print("Your variable is: " + str(lists[z]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `locals()` if you really need it's very very unsafe.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [5,6,7]
z = input("Enter which variable to use x or y: ")
locals().get(z)
```

Comment: this is awesome , though this was not my question but happy to know locals()